# Animating Opacity

Tags: transparency

I'm building a project in which I want to have semi transparent objects for AR. As per screenshot, my floating screen object is semi transparent and also, there is a fade in animation.

If I render my project, image is semi transparent and in Blender, animation runs correctly. But after I export my model/animations as a glTF and import them in Reality Converter to create an USDZ file, which I import in Xcode for AR, there is no transparency. The object is completely opaque, as on the second screenshot.

How can I export objects with different opacity values?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#blend-modes) shows how to setup material so it exports with transparency. glTF doesn't support animation of material properties like alpha.

Comment: Thank you, I was reading the docs, I skipped that one. I'm guessing it might also be very expensive for mobile devices to render semi-transparent object in real time.